# How to write type definition (typescript) for getter/setter

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

How would I write the type definition file (d.ts) for a javascript code that looks like this

**library.js:**

```
Object.defineProperty( SceneNode.prototype, 'name', {
    set: function(name)
    {
        this.setName( name );
    },
    get: function(){
        return this._name;
    },
    enumerable: true
});
```

I have so far:

**library.d.ts**

```
class SceneNode{
    private _name: string;
}
```

But how would I include the getter/setter into the type definition?

Edit 1:

Added file name for clarification

Comment: Is it intended to use setter/getter or you can make two functions `getName()` and `setName()`?

Comment: The library I'm trying to write the d.ts file for is written with getters/setter in this format:
Object.defineProperty( SceneNode.prototype, 'name', {

Comment: @Mouneer why when JS allows for true property accessors?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I love being explicit.

Comment: @Thor_Bux, What do u think? 
`class SceneNode {
  private name: string;

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }
}`

Comment: Yes I'd write it similar if I were to write the library again with ES6 or Typescript. The thing is that the library I need to write typings for is written as mentioned above and at the moment there is no way for me to rewrite it. That is why I'm asking how to write the type definition for the existing code.

Comment: Ok I think this would be enough `declare class SceneNode {
  name: string;
}`

Comment: That looks too easy to be true ;-). Will try thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would just define the type as though it were a simple attribute. The point of the getter and setter is to make it look as though it is only a simple attribute when in fact some code is running, but it doesn't change the interface from a type view.

So all you need is:

```
class SceneNode{
    private _name: string;
    public name: string;
}
```

Comment: Just one follow-up question: Do I need the private and the public definition or would the public be sufficient? The object itself has both ```_name``` and ```name```

Comment: I would include both, because that describes the object more accurately. If you were defining an interface then you wouldn't have the private members but for a class you should have. But that's just opinion: omitting the private member probably won't break anything.